# kong-ingress-controller: Error with ingress in GKE

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kong

i have a big progres, now i'm generating the certificates with this ingress (using certmanager.k8s.io):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    configuration.konghq.com: sample-kong-ingress
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"a big json"}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: name-public-ip
  generation: 14
  name: name-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "11158958"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/name-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: kong-proxy
    servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.a.host.com
    secretName: a-name-to-secret-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

but, now i'm getting this error:

> Reason: ingress default/name-ingress uses unsupported LBType
>   LoadBalancer for cloud provider

*Maybe someone who uses GKE has some idea?*
Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: no, i never really solved it